# How to install libraries in Google Colab?

Tags: bash, google-colaboratory

I'd need to install couple of libraries in Google Colab environment. The one of them is **zimg** coming from this repo https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg

I have the following script to build the library originally taken [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AV1/comments/109jts0/guide_installing_av1an_on_ubuntu_2204/)

```
!git clone https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg
%cd /content/zimg
!git submodule update --init --recursive
!./configure
!make
!sudo make install
```

..but the problem is that configure script was not found **/bin/bash: ./configure: No such file or directory**

```
Cloning into 'zimg'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 13135, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1934/1934), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (718/718), done.
remote: Total 13135 (delta 1317), reused 1715 (delta 1200), pack-reused 11201
Receiving objects: 100% (13135/13135), 3.07 MiB | 8.17 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9547/9547), done.
/content/zimg
Submodule 'graphengine' (https://github.com/sekrit-twc/graphengine.git) registered for path 'graphengine'
Submodule 'test/extra/googletest' (https://github.com/google/googletest.git) registered for path 'test/extra/googletest'
Cloning into '/content/zimg/graphengine'...
Cloning into '/content/zimg/test/extra/googletest'...
Submodule path 'graphengine': checked out 'ce722fdea018040bc38bec1c5ade70239455a564'
Submodule 'googletest' (https://github.com/google/googletest.git) registered for path 'graphengine/test/googletest'
Cloning into '/content/zimg/graphengine/test/googletest'...
Submodule path 'graphengine/test/googletest': checked out 'e2239ee6043f73722e7aa812a459f54a28552929'
Submodule path 'test/extra/googletest': checked out 'e2239ee6043f73722e7aa812a459f54a28552929'
/bin/bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

How could I work around this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, the missing part was run of [*autoreconf*](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html) command what is responsible for automatically rebuild *configure* script.

```
#Install libtool package
!apt-get install libtool

!git clone https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg
%cd /content/zimg
!git submodule update --init --recursive
#option -i, –install: copy missing auxiliary files
!autoreconf -i
!./configure
!make
!sudo make install
```